# GraphQL streaming type?

Tags: javascript, streaming, graphql, graphql-js

I'm playing around with [GraphQL-JS](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) right now, wiring it up to a MariaDB backend.

I've figured out how to return an entire result set:

```
const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
        users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(userType),
            resolve: (root, args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                db.query('select * from users', (err, rows, fields) => {
                    if(err) return reject(err);
                    resolve(rows);
                });
            }),
        }
    })
});
```

Which is pretty cool, but the [library I'm using](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) also lets me [stream results](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows), row-by-row.

Does GraphQL have anything to facilitate this?

As far as I can tell, `GraphQLList` is expecting a full array, and I can only resolve my result set once, not feed using an Emitter or something.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not really a complete answer, but doesn't fit into a comment either)

According to the graphQL spec. it should be possible :

> GraphQL provides a number of built‐in scalars, but **type systems can
>   add additional scalars** with semantic meaning. For example, a GraphQL
>   system could define a scalar called Time which, while serialized as a
>   string, promises to conform to ISO‐8601. When querying a field of type
>   Time, you can then rely on the ability to parse the result with an
>   ISO‐8601 parser and use a client‐specific primitive for time. Another
>   example of a potentially useful custom scalar is Url, which serializes
>   as a string, but is guaranteed by the server to be a valid URL.

So the structure should look like this :

```
var myStream = new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: "myStream",
    serialize: ...
    parseValue: ...
    parseLiteral: ...
  });
}
```

Now I guess you could try to return promises/streams and see what happens, but I don't think it is supported yet. Many people are asking for this, and I think I saw a comment from someone on the graphQL team saying that they are looking into this (cannot find it back unfortunately).

A personal opinion, but if it cannot be changed without incorporating that behaviour into the core of graphQL, may show that graphQL as it is today is not that flexible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to stream results with basic GraphQL server because it has a client-server architecture (you send HTTP request and get HTTP response back).

It's possible with subscriptions, though. They were [recently added](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/189) to GraphQL (see [the story behind](https://kadira.io/blog/graphql/subscriptions-in-graphql)).

Comment: I think when I wrote this I wanted `resolve` to allow for generator return types or some other stream. The HTTP response wouldn't be sent until the generator/stream has been exhausted/closed. I'll check out these links you posted. Streaming responses would be even cooler, but probably harder to work with.

Comment: If you can wait with the response until you have all the data collected, simply keep returning promises, and only collect the values and return an array when you get to the end of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

See the GraphQL @stream directive, example https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby-stream-defer-demo